# How to write a swap function in assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, swap

I've been trying to figure out how to write a x86 GAS swap function for my program. I know its easier to do xchg or just write it C, but I want to be able to write it out anyways.

On my 1st midterm we were given this as as swap function:

```
movl 8(%ebp), %edx
movl 12(%ebp), %ecx
movl (%edx), %ebx
movl (%ecx), %eax
movl %eax, (%edx)
movl %ebx, (%ecx)
```

but I receive a segmentation fault when running this. Haven't been able to succeed in finding my answer anywhere else on the web, so much help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

C CODE:

```
void program2()
{
int numA[2] = {5,10};
int *num1 = &numA[0];
int *num2 = &numA[1];
int loop=0;
printf("stop3\n");
for(loop=0;loop<=10;loop++)
{
    *num1 *=2;
    *num2 *=3;
    printf("%d\n%d\n",*num1,*num2);
    _asSwap(*num1,*num2);
    printf("stop5\n");
    printf("P2num1= %d\n P2num2= %d\n",*num1,*num2);

}
```

Assembly:

```
_asSwap:
push    %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp

movl 8(%ebp), %edx
movl 12(%ebp), %ecx
movl (%edx), %ebx
movl (%ecx), %eax
movl %eax, (%edx)
movl %ebx, (%ecx)

pop %ebp
ret
```

Comment: Seems to me that the 2 parameters being supplied are pointers to 32-bit integers? If you aren't passing pointers to integers to this code then I'd more than likely expect it to segfault. Maybe you were just passing integer values rather than pointers to integers?

Comment: Okay I'll try pointers right now.

Comment: nope, didn't work. Atleast, not pointers to an array. Here is my C code `void program2()
{
 int numA[2] = {5,10};
 int *num1 = &numA[0];
 int *num2 = &numA[1];
 int loop=0;
 printf("stop3\n");
 for(loop=0;loop<=10;loop++)
 {
  *num1 *=2;
  *num2 *=3;
  printf("%d\n%d\n",*num1,*num2);
  _asSwap(*num1,*num2);
  printf("stop5\n");
  printf("P2num1= %d\n P2num2= %d\n",*num1,*num2);

 }`

Comment: I'd have to see the entire assembler function and how it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed the values, not the pointers.  If you'd included the prototype in your C, the compiler would have caught that (instead of warning about an un-declared function, and assuming it took int parameters).

```
extern int _asSwap(int *a, int *b);
```

A debugger would also have caught this, if you checked the address that segfaulted.

Also, it's not normal to prefix your C function names with `_`.  OS X prefixes `_` onto C symbol names, and so did Linux a.out (now replaced by ELF).  So you in some cases need a leading `_` in the asm, but don't use it in C.

Comment: yes you are right, thank you. It's been awhile since I did pointers haha. yea I didn't realize I was passing the dereferenced pointer. Much appreciated.

Comment: Funny, pointers were my first guess and that was with incomplete information ;-). Didn't see that he updated the comments and his answer with code I requested. I was too slow. Got onto a different question!